# Showing that $\sum a_n (x-3)^n$ converges/diverges at certain points

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\sum a_n (x-3)^n$ converges at x=10. Then does it converge or diverge at the following points: $x = -4, x = 9, x=11?$

The question does not tell me what $a_n$ is, so we have to assume it can be anything (but it converges at x=10)

So if it converges there, then the certain radius of convergence should be at least 1 right? That means at 9 and 11 it converges. I have no idea about $x=-4$ though.

Comment: You know that the radius of convergence centered at $x=3$ is at least $7$.  Of course, it's possible that $x=10$ is on the boundary of the radius of convergence.

Comment: @RobertShore so does it converge or diverge at the points $-4, 9, 11$?

Answer (score 2):

you are right to be suspicious about the case $x = -4$. suppose:
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{(-7)^n n}
$$

Comment: What about at 9 and 11?

Comment: Thank you for answering btw

Answer (score 1):

Right, on the circle of convergence,  there are examples where there is convergence at some but not all points.

For instance,  $\sum (x-3)^n/n $ converges absolutely on $|x-3|=1$ except at $4$.

Also,  it might not converge at $x=11$, since $11$ is further from  $3$ than $10$.

Comment: Could you also talk about $x=9$? Thank you.

Comment: Since $9$ is within  $7$ units of $3$, it converges there.  The radius of convergence is at least $7$.